# How do I properly manage a directory listing within a buffer?

Tags: buffers, netrw

I use a mix of buffers and split panes to manage my workflow. Sometimes, I (perhaps accidentally) open a directory listing instead of a file. My buffers may look like this then:

[image: directory listing]

At this point, I can `:bnext` or `:bprevious` to bounce between my buffers, but when in the directory listing I cannot `:bp  <BAR>` as I would normally to close a buffer and I'm seemingly stuck with this awkward buffer that I can't remove. (I have these all `nmap`ed in some capacity, FWIW)

Yes, my habits should get me to use `CTRL+P` more to search for files, but sometimes I find this method of file traversal useful, so understanding the proper way to manage these would be superb.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call a directory listing is actually a special buffer with type `netrw`.  It is created by a plugin also called `netrw`. Your issue probably stems from the fact that `netrw` (with the default listing) creates *several* hidden buffers, one for each directory listing you pass through, i.e. every time you change directory a new hidden buffer is created.

But your question is about how to *manage* the directory listing. `netrw` can be opened from within Vimin different ways, and, probably, at least one of these ways will prove more useful to your workflow.  You can open `netrw` with:

- `:Explore`: The default,
- `:Hexplore`: In a horizontal split,
- `:Lexlplore`: Left split that can be used as a toggle,
- `:Sexplore`: Horizontal split using the current's file CWD,
- `:Vexplore`: As `Sexplore` but in a vertical split.
- `:Texplore`: In a new tab.

And there is also `:Rexplore` which returns the current window to a previous buffer that is not a `netrw` buffer.  In other words, you can use `:Rex` to exit from the directory listing into the closest regular buffer.

Yet, I'd definitely suggest to you to explore (pun intended) the other options of running the `netrw` listing.  Personally I find:

```
:22Lexplore
```

To be extremely useful.

---

Extra note: `netrw` has several global variables that can be set inside your `vimrc` to customize how the listing looks and behaves.  See `:help netrw` for an extensive list.

Comment: Ah, so fascinating and useful. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

When you end up in a netrw window you can do `<C-^>` (or `<C-6>`, depending on your keyboard layout) to switch to "the alternate file".

In this case, "the alternate file" is simply the buffer that was previously displayed in the current window.

`<C-^>` is a global command not related to `netrw`. See `:help ctrl-^`.